# How to change the format of the data generated by FormBuilder

Tags: angular

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.pgForm = this.fb.group({
      pgroup: ['', Validators.required],
      needs: this.fb.array([this.fb.control('')]),
    });

  }

  get needs() {
    return this.pgForm.get('needs') as FormArray;
  }
  addNeed() {
    this.needs.push(this.fb.control(''));
  }
```

gives out a myForm.value that looks like this..

```
Values: { "pgroup": "blah", "needs": [ "blah", "blah", "blah" ]}
```

I want a myForm.value that looks like this; so that it will talk well with my API

```
Values: 
{ "pgroup": "blah", 
  "needs": [ 
        {"need": "blah"}, 
        {"need": "blah"}, 
        {"need": "blah"}
   ]
}
```

Is it possible to work it out on formBuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will have to push a formgroup to the array.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.pgForm = this.fb.group({
      pgroup: ['', Validators.required],
      needs: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({ need: [''])]),
    });

  }

  get needs() {
    return this.pgForm.get('needs') as FormArray;
  }
  addNeed() {
    this.needs.push(this.fb.group({ need: [''] }));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `FormControl` you will have to have a `FormGroup` with `name:` `FormControl` inside the array:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.pgForm = this.fb.group({
    pgroup: ['', Validators.required],
    needs: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({ need: this.fb.control('') })])
  });
}
```

And the same when adding:

```
addNeed() {
  this.needs.push(this.fb.group({ need: this.fb.control('') }));
}
```